# Passing cdk --context key=value using AWS Connector for GitHub

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-devops, aws-pipeline

I am trying to pass the context value while using AWS Connector for GitHub code commit.
I have two branches dev and main. If code is committed on the dev branch my cdk app should receive an environment variable with the value dev.

I don't want to declare these environment variables in my code. After getting the environment variable my stack setup resources accordingly. I am constructing a pipeline for dev and prod in cdk app.
Or is there any other way to get the environment variable in cdk app?

Comment: Your CDK code is just regular code - use the language's built-in method of fetching environment variables. (`os.getenv` in Python)

Comment: @gshpychka can you please share where I should set the env values equal to dev. If you can share a small example of setting the values ?